# Куда делись опубликованные ранее исследования?

Tags: поддержка, хэшкод

На HashCode была возможность публиковать исследования. Сейчас я не могу найти ни ранее опубликованные, ни добавить новое. Подскажите, они утрачены или просто хорошо спрятаны?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Исследования *не нужны*.

1. Если "исследование" подходит под формат сайта, например, предоставляет конкретное решение каких-то проблем, то его можно оформить в виде вопроса и ответа. С некоторыми исследованиями именно так и поступили, например, что-то можно найти среди ответов Влада.
2. Если "исследование" представляет собой вброс некоторого объёма неструктурированной информации с предложением обсудить со всех сторон, программистский юмор и тому подобное, то подобное содержимое более не вписывается в рамки сайта. Вы можете опубликовать свои размышления на стороннем ресурсе, который более подходит под этот формат, например, на программистском форуме.

На самом сайте "исследования" отсутствуют. Вы можете воспользоваться [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150328064500/https://ru.stackoverflow.com/research/) для получения текста. Если возникнут проблемы, можете обратиться к Николасу: думаю, он бережно хранит бэкапы у себя на всякий случай, и в случае чего может предоставить потерянный текст. Впрочем, всё ценное уже было перенесено вскоре после переезда, если мне не изменяет память.

Comment: Я, кстати, перетащил одно исследование сюда вручную.

Answer (score 1):

Исследования был упразднены, так как в движке Stack Exchange такого функционала не было и не планировалось его добавлять.

Сами исследования были перенесены на Stack Overflow на русском в виде вопросов без ответа. Пожалуйста, проверьте их наличие. Если какое-либо исследование было потеряно при переходе, пожалуйста, сообщите мне. Я вручную перенесу его из последнего дампа базы данных ХэшКода.

Comment: Нет. Просто нашел интересную штуку и хотел предупредить о ней других разработчиков php :)

Comment: @dimka3210 Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [вопросы со своим ответом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)?