# Коллективное ведение блога сообщества

Tags: обсуждение

Спешу предложить инициативу коллективного ведения блога сообществом! Как многие могут знать, у компании Stack Overflow есть блог: https://stackoverflow.blog/. В целом блог делится на три основных раздела:

1. Новости компании, исследования, подкаст (кстати, крайне интересный!) и т. д.
2. Более или менее технические публикации сотрудников компании.
3. Все остальное.

Где–то в разделе новостей компании затерялись [блоги международных сообществ](https://stackoverflow.blog/international/) (на данный момент блог ведет только сообщество Stack Overflow на испанском).

Как мне кажется, нашему сообществу блог мог бы пойти на пользу: мы сможем рассказать друг другу то, что нам интересно, но выходит за рамки вопросов и ответов по программированию.

> **Блог сообщества нужен, чтобы рассказывать сообществу про его участников и их увлечения.**

#### Какие типы статей можно публиковать?

**Полноценные статьи**

Самодостаточные статьи, идея которых полностью раскрыта в самих публикациях.

**Вводные к публикациям в личном блоге**

Если у вас есть блог и вы считаете, что в нем есть интересные сообществу публикации (в том числе технические), вы можете написать вводную к ним и разместить в вводный материал в блоге сообщества, добавив ссылку на исходную публикацию на вашем блоге (например, [так](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/03/29/stack-overflow-the-hardware-2016-edition/)).

#### На какие темы можно писать в блог?

- Все, что касается сообщества, но по каким–то причинам не подходит для [основного сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) или [Меты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/). Например, какую–либо статистику, интересные материалы и идеи, которыми вы бы хотели поделиться с коллегами, или просто ваши наблюдения и заметки.
- Вводные к развернутым техническим публикациям в вашем личном блоге.
- Рассказ о вас, вашем месте работы, ваших интересных проектах выходного дня, увлечениях и т. д. Пожалуйста, помните, материал не должен быть рекламный. Например, было бы здорово почитать про интересные и нестандартные подходы к организации личного пространства или рабочих процессов на реальных примерах. Основная задача таких публикаций – рассказать коллегам о возможных нестандартных творческих начинаниях.
- Ваши идеи по тому, как нам улучшить наш (всех и каждого) опыт участия в сообществе.

Какие публикации размещать не стоит:

- Обучающие материалы по программированию. Пожалуйста, если вы хотите поделиться знаниями с сообществом, используйте более подходящее место – сайт вопросов и ответов. Разбейте вашу статью не несколько подтем, напишите к каждой вопрос и разместите на сайте. Сайт вопросов и ответов посещает много ваших коллег, и на нем ваша интересная информация по программированию будет полезнее!
- Статьи, подразумевающие ответ. Для обсуждений есть более подходящее место – [Мета](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/).

#### Как разместить публикацию в блоге?

Процесс публикации крайне прост и выглядит следующим образом:

1. Заинтересованный участник пишет публикацию либо введение к публикации в случае публикации в своем блоге.
2. Выбирает картинку для публикации.
3. Присылает размеченный текст публикации и ссылку на изображение мне на почту (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com).
4. При необходимости поясняет, какую атрибуцию мне следует указывать (по умолчанию это будет псевдоним со Stack Overflow), а также любые другие пожелания.

Публикация будет размещена от моего имени с соответствующей атрибуцией. В будущем постараюсь найти возможность создать специального автора «Дух сообщества», чтобы все публикации нашего сообщества публиковал Дух с необходимой атрибуцией.

#### Пожалуйста, предложите ваши идеи по ведению блога сообщества!

Сообщество – это не один управляющий! Сообщество Stack Overflow – это мы все! Если вы считаете, что блог нашего сообщества должен выглядеть по–другому или он не нужен вовсе, пожалуйста, расскажите всем об этом! Сообществу крайне важно ваше мнение!

Comment: Сдаётся мне, будет проблема с периодичностью публикаций за авторством участников.

Comment: @Arhad Это не беда. Частота в две публикации в месяц уже будет достаточной в купе с вопросами на Мете, обсуждениями в чате и видеочатом. Основная идея дать возможность участникам сообщества способ поделиться своими интересами, рассказать о себе сообществу. Это только для нас. Задачи стать Интернет СМИ нет. Качество в этом случае сильно важнее количества, как мне кажется.

Comment: О, а вот и пример «вводной» (как вы назвали) статьи: https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/22/stack-overflow-flipped-switch-https/

Comment: Не понятно по поводу "необходимой атрибуции", имеется в виду авторство?

Comment: @Cerbo На данный момент нет возможности (на сколько я знаю) опубликовать статью в блоге от вашего имени. Под «необходимой атрибуцией» я имею в виду, что публикация, опубликованная от моего имени (а в будущем, надеюсь, от имени «Духа»), будет иметь необходимое пояснение, что она не моя, а ваша.

Comment: *Присылает размеченный текст публикации и ссылку на изображение* какая должна быть разметка? md/html или можно Word?

Comment: @Barmaley Ранее мы использовали Jekyll, то есть MarkDown разметку. Сейчас, вроде бы, перешли обратно на WordPress.

Comment: Я так понимаю, статья должна быть на английском?

Comment: @Suvitruf на русском.

Answer (score 5):

Вот мои идеи для блога:

- Отчёты со встреч участников сообщества.
- Отчёты о видеоконференциях, краткий план их повестки и текстовая расшифровка видео.
- Туда же можно (наверное) перенести бюллетени сообщества.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Отчеты о встрече было бы здорово делать, так же как бюллетени сообщества!

Comment: Пока был на одной встрече и не думаю, что там есть о чем отчитываться )

Comment: @Nofate, просто попили чай и разошлись? Ничего не обсуждали?

Comment: @Arhad попили отличного крафтового пива и сидра, познакомились и потравили историй.

Comment: @Nofate, во, уже есть затравка статьи. :-)

Comment: @Arhad "Социальная значимость алкоголизма в молодежной среде".

Answer (score 1):

(у меня с семиклашками на занятия по биоинформатике ходит упорная пятиклашка, так вот она сидит на задней парте и поднимает руку с видом "можно, мне, можно мне" :)) - так и я сейчас :)

Мой первый вопрос [Нагруженные деревья в биоинформатике. Часть 1. Точный поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753397/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-1-%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA), скоро выльется во вторую часть, а затем, возможно, в третью. Как мне мнится, сам вопрос + ответы на него (причесанные) вполне тянут на статью в блоге. Так почему бы сообществу не завести свой блог вот для таких (полу-)обзорных материалов?

Comment: Похоже на [хэшкодовские исследования](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1907/208074). К слову, @NicolasChabanovsky,  может, тогда имеет смысл выложить в блог весь тот материал, что не был перемещён при переезде?

Comment: У блога как такового есть свои недостатки (это отдельный сайт, проблемы индексации и тд): размещать подобные публикации в блоге не стоит, как и просто копировать туда материал — на основном сайте вопрос с ответом будет полезен куда большему количеству людей! На мой взгляд, блог нужен для того, чтобы увлечь других людей нашими увлечениями. Как результат, вероятно, в блог бы хорошо вписались выжимки из подобных статей, с объяснением прикладной значимости результатов. Пожалуйста, в любое время высылайте подобные заметки мне, я с радостью их опубликую в блоге сообщества с указанием авторства!

Comment: @Arhad Да, было бы здорово в каком–либо виде разместить исследования на Stack Overflow на русском. Пожалуйста, напишите мне в общем чате сообщества, если у вас есть какие–либо идеи на этот счет. Постараемся их осуществить вместе!