# Свой блог для Stack Overflow на Русском

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

К примеру, есть:

- [Stack Overflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/).
- [Super User blog](https://blog.superuser.com/).

У нас можно ли завести такой блог, где будут публиковаться интересные/полезные вещи?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Платформа блогов Stack Exchange [была закрыта](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291741/274323). «Закрыта» — означает, что проект свернули. https://stackoverflow.blog/ — это больше блог, который ведется сотрудниками компании, а не участниками сообщества, хотя в нем много разделов, один из которых посвящен сообществу.

Русскоязычное сообщество — неотъемлемая часть Stack Overflow, поэтому у нас тоже есть свой раздел на https://stackoverflow.blog/ ([например](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/06/28/welcome-stackoverflow-in-russian-blog/)). Он активно не ведется, потому что я лично предпочитаю [Мету](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/). Мета выигрывает у блога, поскольку на ней можно не только публиковать [анонсы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B8), но и [обсуждать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8653/6) проблемы всем сообществом.

Про коллективное ведение блога я писал отдельно в вопросе «[Коллективное ведение блога сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5252/6)». На сколько я понимаю, все предложенное в том вопросе остается в силе.

Answer (score 7):

Оно уже есть в каком-то виде [тут](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/06/28/welcome-stackoverflow-in-russian-blog/), но, вроде бы, является мертворожденным созданием. За два с половиной года других записей не появилось.

Comment: Хм.. а почему мы тогда английский блог переводим на мете, а не в блоге?

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня нет доступа к блогу. А тем, у кого есть доступ, вероятно, это не интересно)

Comment: Я посмотрел минут 5 и абсолютно никаких мыслей, как этим можно воспользоваться, чтобы писать свои заметки в какой-то свой раздел (т.е.  именно вести блог) не возникло

Comment: @Qwertiy ну, перевод это всё же другое. Я так понимаю, что свой блог должен предполагать именно свой контент, а не переводы.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, вроде бы одно другому не мешает)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ответ прост — мне нравится Мета, так как на Мете можно получать обратную связь, есть коллективная правка и т.д. То, что в других сообществах публиковалось в блоге, я публиковал на Мете.

Comment: Про блог сообщества я отдельно писал как–то: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5252/6